# Create an remote directory using SFTP / RCurl

Tags: r, sftp, rcurl

Is it possible to create a directory on an SFTP site using the RCurl package? I found the [sftp_create_dirs](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2007-06/att-0136/sftp_create_dirs.func) function, but I could not find an example how to use it.

I tried to set the `ftp.create.missing.dirs` option to `TRUE`, as in

```
library(RCurl)
opts <- list(ftp.create.missing.dirs=TRUE, 
    ssh.public.keyfile = mypubkey, ssh.private.keyfile = myprivatekey)
ftpUpload("myfile.txt", "sftp://me@www.host.org/newdir/myfile.txt", .opts=opts)
```

This works if `newdir` exists, but fails if it does not exists.

Any hint appreciated!

Comment: Can you create an empty directory first and then add the file?

Comment: It simply works now. Don't know why if failed first, sorry I wasted your time.