# How to upload a directory folder via RCurl

Tags: r, ftp-client, rcurl

I tried to upload a directory into a ftp server via the RCurl command :

```
ftpUpload(myFolder, paste0("ftp://user:pw@domain.com/public_html/", myFolder))
```

but in the server  it created a file and not a directory

what I wrong ?

Thanks in advance !
Alberto

Comment: Not sure the function is intended to create folders... can you create the directory manually with an ftp client and then try uploading the files per se?

Comment: Thanks Dominic. The problem is that I have a lot of subdirectory .. and they change as a function of the task that I do.

Comment: I found this question that could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181690/create-an-remote-directory-using-sftp-rcurl