# Unable to create folder with RCurl

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I'm having trouble using the `ftpUpload()` function of `RCurl` to upload a file to a non-existent folder in an SFTP. I want the folder to be made if its not there, using the `ftp.create.missing.dirs` option. Here's my code currently:

```
.opts <- list(ftp.create.missing.dirs=TRUE)

ftpUpload(what = "test.txt", 
to "sftp://ftp.testserver.com:22/newFolder/existingfile.txt", 
userpwd = paste(user, pwd, sep = ":"), .opts = opts)`
```

It doesn't seem to be working as I get the following error:

```
* Initialized password authentication
* Authentication complete
* Failed to close libssh2 file
```

I can upload a file to an existent folder with success, its just when the folder isn't there I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems be due the fact you are trying to create the new folder, as seen in this question: [Create an remote directory using SFTP / RCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181690/create-an-remote-directory-using-sftp-rcurl)

The error can be found in Microsoft R Open git page:

```
case SSH_SFTP_CLOSE:
  if(sshc->sftp_handle) {
    rc = libssh2_sftp_close(sshc->sftp_handle);
    if(rc == LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN) {
      break;
    }
    else if(rc < 0) {
      infof(data, "Failed to close libssh2 file\n");
    }
    sshc->sftp_handle = NULL;
  }
  if(sftp_scp)
    Curl_safefree(sftp_scp->path);
```

In the code the parameter `rc` is related to `libssh2_sftp_close` function (more info here https://www.libssh2.org/libssh2_sftp_close_handle.html), that tries close the nonexistent directory, resulting in the error.

Try use curlPerform as:

```
curlPerform(url="ftp.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/";, postquote="MkDir /newFolder/", userpwd="user:pass")
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. That makes perfect sense. Do you know of a way I can just create a folder on the SFTP with `RCurl` without trying to upload a file? Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I added a possible alternative, take a look.

Comment: Yes! It worked. However, I needed to do a little alteration to get it to work with `R Studio`. Here's my slight adaptation in case it comes in handy to anyone: 


`curlPerform(url="ftp.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/";, postquote="MkDir /newFolder/", userpwd="user:pass")` 


Just changed the `MKD` to `MkDir` and `quote` to `postquote`, but principles of your original still intact!
Many thanks once again

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Thanks for your contribution, I`ll improve my answer.